# Core Graphics- drawRect: not getting called frequently enough

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, drawrect

In my application, I have a UIViewController with a subclassed UIView (and several other elements) inside of it. Inside of the UIView, called DrawView, in my `drawRect:` method, I draw a table grid type thing, and plot an array of CGPoints on the grid. When the user taps on the screen, it calls `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and checks to find the closest point on the grid to the touch, adds a point to the array that the `drawRect:` method draws points from, and calls `[self setNeedsDisplay]`. As the user moves their finger around the screen, it checks to see if the point changed from the last location, and updates the point and calls `[self setNeedsDisplay]` as necessary.

This works great in the Simulator. However, when run on a real iPhone, it runs very slowly, when you move your finger around, it lags in drawing the dot. I have read that running calculations for where to place the points in a different thread can improve performance. Does anyone have experience with this that knows this for a fact? Any other suggestions to reduce lag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any other suggestions to reduce lag?

Yes.  Don't use `-drawRect:`.  It's a long and complicated reason why, but basically when UIKit sees that you've implemented `-drawRect:` in your `UIView` subclass, rendering goes through the really slow software-based rendering path.  When you draw with `CALayer` objects and composite views, you can get hardware accelerated graphics, which can make your app FAR more performant.

Comment: Great answer. But how would you do that? User different view each with a layer or one view with multiple sublayers?

Comment: @Sandro either would work, but I would probably use `UIView` objects instead of `CALayers`, because that leaves the possibility of attaching gesture recognizers, dealing with ObjC types instead of CF types (UIImage vs CGImageRef, etc)...

Comment: Thanks. I'm kind of newish and I have absolutely no idea what CALayer objects or composite views are. I found [Apple's documentation on CALayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html), but are there any other tutorials or documentation that you recommend learning about these things, and how to use them to draw with?

Comment: @josherick By "composite views", I mean "add views as subviews of other views".  You're compositing them together, i.e. layering them on top of each other.  ("composite" is being used as a verb, not an adjective)

Comment: wait, really? that seems like it would take a lot of memory, drawing a grid out of UIViews. and how would i draw lines connecting the points? or even a circle (point)?

Comment: @Josherick yeah, there's a bit of a memory penalty for doing this, but it's MUCH faster. As for drawing a grid, you can draw that into an image, and then slap the image into a `UIImageView`, and then never have to redraw it again.